# gnuplot: how to skip rows with 0 in a column?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, skip

I need to extract the row of data where the absolute difference of y(block_1)-pt is less than a certain limit. If more than one row satisfies this condition, I need to retrieve the row with the smallest difference.

```
$Data <<EOD
# block_1   # block_2
x y         x y
1 1979.2    2 2027
1 1598.6    2 1591.4
1 1430.8    2 1401.6
1 1544.7    2 1923.7
1 1953.3    2 1677
1 1288.8    2 1311.1
1 1741.3    2 1689.3
1 1791.1    2 2015.8
EOD

set key autotitle columnhead

pt = 1953.1
limit = 0.5

absDiff(col,x) = abs( column(col) - x ) < limit

set table $Temp
    plot $Data u ( absDiff( 2, pt ) ):( $4 ) w table
unset table

print $Temp
```

The result is:

```
 0       2027
 0       1591.4
 0       1401.6
 0       1923.7
 1       1677
 0       1311.1
 0       1689.3
 0       2015.8
```

How can I skip all rows that contain a 0 in the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gnuplot>5.4.0 you can use the experimental feature "conditional writing to a table" (check `help with table`). If you are bound to versions <5.4.0, there are other solutions.

If you change your plot `with table` command to

```
plot $Data u ( absDiff( 2, pt ) ):4 w table if absDiff( 2, pt )
```

the result will be:

```
 1       1677
```

**Addition:** finding the minimum difference without giving a limit and using `stats`.

You better skip the line `x y    x y` because it is no valid data line and it will shift the row index by one. Row indices are zero-based.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.0, because of use of datablocks, `stats` works also with earlier 4.x versions)

```
### find minimum difference and corresponding row
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# block_1   # block_2
x y         x y
1 1979.2    2 2027
1 1598.6    2 1591.4
1 1430.8    2 1401.6
1 1544.7    2 1923.7
1 1953.3    2 1677
1 1288.8    2 1311.1
1 1741.3    2 1689.3
1 1791.1    2 2015.8
EOD

pt = 1953.1

stats $Data u 4:(abs($2-pt)) skip 1 nooutput

print sprintf("Minimum difference is: %g",STATS_min_y)
print sprintf("Located in row:        %g",STATS_index_min_y)
print sprintf("Value in column 4 is:  %g",STATS_pos_min_y)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Minimum difference is: 0.2
Located in row:        4
Value in column 4 is:  1677
```

Comment: Great! Printing both y-values is even shorter: `plot $Data u 2:4 w table if absDiff( 2, pt )`

Comment: @magfan actually, you wanted the minimum difference, but you can also do this without giving a limit. I will post an example in a minute.